# C# Dictonary поиск по string ключу

Tags: c#, словари

Есть Dictonary  заполненный данными.
Ключ строка вида:  2019-12-28 11:00:00Z

Когда делаю поиск по ключу,присваивая значение переменной string, пишет что значений нет.

Присваиваю переменной значение:

```
   string searchKey = "2019-12-28 11:00:00Z";
```

Вставляю переменную:

```
        string tex7;

        tex7 = Dictonary2020.yearOutTest[searchKey];
```

Ошибка нет такого ключа.

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: "The given key '2019-12-28 11:00:00Z' was not present in the dictionary."

https://youtu.be/Ru7mtjNKo7M

Ссылка на видео для неверящих и минусующих.

Comment: Покажите, как он заполнен этими данными. Напишите например `foreach (var item in Dictonary2020.yearOutTest) Debug.WriteLine($"[{item.Key}] {item.Value}");` и дайте нам результат. А вообще, научитесь делать отладку приложения, научитесь ставить точки остановки и смотреть то, что находится внутри объектов.

Comment: Взял ваш код и набросал в Linqpad небольшой скрипт для проверки: добавил ваш searchKey и попытался его найти. И всё находится! Сделайте пожалуйста [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Перед тем, как искать значение по ключу в словаре, нужно добавить это значение с этим ключем в словарь

Comment: Ссылка на видео для неверующих. https://youtu.be/Ru7mtjNKo7M

Comment: Это видео в котором вы сплитите по запятой, но не убираете пробел? ну так себе аргумент

Comment: Данные из файла заполняют словарь, потом словарь выводится на экран, потом идет поиск по словарю. И выдает ошибку.

Comment: +1 за усилия по демонстрации. Про пробел Вам уже сказали.

Comment: На вашем видео видно что [ в начале и пробел перед запятой попадает в ключ для словаря. Посмотрите же что вам консоль на вашем же видео пишет

Comment: Сейчас попробую убрать все пробелы и скобки, спасибо.

Comment: Всем спасибо большое! Извините, что занял ваше время.